# Tasker set Variables for usage in KWGT Widget not working correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

The API I am getting data from is responding with an array of the seasons in the game Valorant. I want to get the current season by looking at the "startTime" and "endTime value inside of the seasons array. If the startTime is behind the current time and the endTime is after the current time, the right season is chosen and should be used to show the values as global values to be used by KWGT.

Unfortunataly it doesn't work and the global values return empty. Could you please help me?

The java script code:

```
var jsonResponse = global('jsonResponse');
var data = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentTimestamp = currentDate.getTime();

for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var season = data.data[i];
    var startTime = new Date(season.startTime).getTime();
    var endTime = new Date(season.endTime).getTime();

    if (startTime <= currentTimestamp && endTime >= currentTimestamp) {
        var seasonName = season.name;
        var seasonStartTime = season.startTime;
        var seasonEndTime = season.endTime;
        break;
    }
}

setGlobal('seasonName', seasonName);
setGlobal('seasonStartTime', seasonStartTime);
setGlobal('seasonEndTime', seasonEndTime);
```

I have also made the code in html, which has bigger possibilities so I will include the java script code I have made for the html version as well:

```js
async function getActInfo() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch("https://valorant-api.com/v1/seasons");
                const data = await response.json();
                const currentDateTime = new Date();

                let closestEpisode = null;

                for (const season of data.data) {
                    const startDate = new Date(season.startTime);
                    const endDate = new Date(season.endTime);

                    if (startDate < currentDateTime && endDate > currentDateTime && season.displayName.includes("EPISODE")) {
                        closestEpisode = season.displayName;
                        break; // Only need to find the closest episode, then stop searching
                    }
                }

                for (const season of data.data) {
                    const startDate = new Date(season.startTime);
                    const endDate = new Date(season.endTime);

                    if (startDate < currentDateTime && endDate > currentDateTime && !season.displayName.includes("EPISODE")) {
                        const actInfoElement = document.getElementById("actInfo");
                        const timeLeftElement = document.getElementById("timeLeft");

                        const timeLeft = endDate - currentDateTime;

                        actInfoElement.textContent = `${closestEpisode || "Unknown Episode"} ${season.displayName}`;
                        timeLeftElement.textContent = formatTimeLeft(timeLeft);

                        setTimeout(getActInfo, 1000); // Update time every second

                        break; // Stop searching after finding the current act
                    }
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching act information:", error);
            }
        }

        function formatTimeLeft(timeLeft) {
            const days = Math.floor(timeLeft / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            const hours = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            const minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            const seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            return `Time Left\n${days}d, ${hours}h, ${minutes}m, ${seconds}s`;
        }

        getActInfo();
```

```css
body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .info-box {
            border-radius: 25px;
            background-color: #0f141a;
            padding: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        #actInfo {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: white;
        }

        #timeLeft {
            margin-top: 10px;
            white-space: pre;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Valorant Act Information</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="info-box">
        <p id="actInfo">Loading...</p>
        <p id="timeLeft">Loading...</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to take the startTime and endTime for each array entry and check if the startTime is before the current time and the endTime is after the current time and choose the array entry if both of these are true. But I can't get it to work properly unfortunately.